# Is there a relation between the triangular numbers and the combinations with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics

**let's say We have 9 identical candies and we want to distribute them between 3 different sections of our bag**. It does not matter which candies go to which section. How many ways do we have to do it? 
its c(11, 2) = 55

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
count=0
for c in combinations_with_replacement("TbL", 9):
  count+=1 

  print("".join(c))

print(count)
```

if you run this simple code you'll see what I mean you'l see that it stops at **exactly triangular number 9** [image]

**Is this a coincidence?**
**One more thing why the formula for the combination with replacement is c(k+n-1, n-1)** I just understand that if there is (n) ingredients then  the number of the delimiters is(n-1) I can see this visually but why we add this number to our elements and choosing (n-1) elements **for example we have Twenty people are voting for one of 5 candidates.  each voter votes for one of 5 candidates. The result of an election is the number of votes for each of the candidate**. in order to calculate How many possible results can this vote have we can apply combinations with repetition simply because one of the candidates gain all of the 20 votes or gain nothing of them. since we know the number of delimiters is 4 but why we add this 4 to the 20 people and then choose 4 c(24, 4) 
**for all I know that our goal is to select four spots for four delimiters so am kinda understand why we choose four but the the subtle part for me is the adding part**

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but if the question is "why do binomial coefficients arise in this sort of problem?" then [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Also not sure what you're asking, but it's worth pointing out that $C(n, 2) = \frac{1}{2}n(n - 1)$ is always a triangle number.

Comment: @lulu yes that's what am asking for

Comment: @lulu I can't figure out the the relation between the binomial coefficients and combinations

Comment: So, that wiki article should answer your question.  Here, of course, you are looking for $3-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $9$.  Thus you should picture $11$ slots (as you have $9$ stars and $2$ bars) and you are simply asking how many ways are there to place the two bars.

Comment: what do you mean by 11 slots @lulu

Comment: in the link you put what is the difference between theorem one and two I get confused @lulu

Comment: Theorem $1$ refers to $n-$ tuples of positive numbers, while Theorem $2$ allows $0$.  In your question, you have a case of theorem $2$ since you can have an empty section or two.  If you required that all sections contain at least one candy you'd use theorem $1$.